# Getting NoClassDefFoundError when using Powermock

Tags: java, powermock, easymock

I am trying to use powermock with easymock to test private and static methods.
I have downloaded jars from GITHUB and added their dependencies in build.gradle but i keep on getting NoClassDefFoundError when I run the testcase.

Here are the stacktrace and dependencies in the gradle:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/reflect/spi/ProxyFramework
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.powermock.reflect.spi.ProxyFramework
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-core', version: '1.4.6'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.5.1'
testCompile group: 'org.easymock', name: 'easymock', version: '4.0.1'
testCompile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version: '3.2.9'
testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile group: 'org.objenesis', name: 'objenesis', version: '3.0.1'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-easymock', version: '2.0.2'
compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.24.0-GA'
```

Comment: Provide the exception details.

Comment: Without providing more details such as the full stacktrace, as well as you build/dependencies file, we can't provide you with any useful help.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/reflect/spi/ProxyFramework
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.reflect.spi.ProxyFramework

Comment: i was getting error when i was posting full stack trace..now posted some part of stack trace above.

Comment: testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-core', version: '1.4.6'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.5.1'
 testCompile group: 'org.easymock', name: 'easymock', version: '4.0.1'
    testCompile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version: '3.2.9'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'

Comment: testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.objenesis', name: 'objenesis', version: '3.0.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-easymock', version: '2.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.24.0-GA'

Comment: @user13596193 Please [edit] your question to include all these information to your question. They belong to the content of your post and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I "think" you did not specify the scope of the dependency. I don't know how you can do it in Gradle but in maven we add "scope" test "scope" to dependencies declaration.